# Validate fields on Lead Conversion

Tags: validation, lead-conversion, validation-rule, inputcheckboxes

I want to ensure that a user cannot convert a lead without ticking three checkboxes (below). Below is my validation rule but it still allows the user to convert the lead. Any ideas?

AND(IsConverted = TRUE,
OR(Owner_Sales__c = FALSE,
Qualified_Lead__c = FALSE,
Potential_Closure = FALSE))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check that the lead settings to make sure that the "Require Validation for Converted Leads" checkbox is checked. By default, leads do not have to pass validation when converting unless that checkbox is checked. You get to this setting by going to Setup>Customize>Leads>Lead Settings. Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also, just add to this item. This was a feature that I first needed to get enabled by Salesforce.com. The checkbox mentioned above was not present by default.

Comment: @Clehan1 I'm glad I could help!